# How do you you reduce the space between paragraph to paragraph

Tags: html, css, margins, line-spacing

I'm trying to make the space that separates the paragraphs smaller. I've tried changing the top and bottom margins in CSS but it doesn't make any major changes, I went all the way down to 00px but no change. I even took out the 
's. Maybe I'm overlooking something but I can't seem to put my finger on it.

```css
#content {
  font: normal 100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 680px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 10px;
  float: left;
}

.content_item {
  width: 680px;
  margin-top: .20px;
  margin-bottom: .20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="content_item">
  
    <h1>Specific project goals are</h1>


    <ul>
      <li>To build the big data and cloud computing research capacity at Winston-Salem state university.</li>
      <li>To involve undergraduate students in cutting-edge research.</li>
      <li>To enhance educational experiences for CS and IT majors at WSSU.
      </li>
      <li>To expand the participation of underrepresented minority, specifically women, in STEM and support the nation’s efforts in building a robust STEM workforce.</li>
    </ul>
    <!--close button_small-->
  </div>
  <!--close content_container-->
</div>



<div id="content">
  <div class="content_item">
  
    <h1>Current Fundings</h1>

    <ul>
      <li>NSF, “Improving Research and Education of Big Data and Cloud Computing at Winston-Salem State University”, <a href="https://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/showAward?AWD_ID=1600864&HistoricalAwards=fal"><strong>Award Number: 1600864</strong>
    </a> $307,802, 2016 – 2019. </li>

      <li>NSF, “Collaborative Research: Excellence In Research: Computational Framework and Data Science for Identification”, <a href="https://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/showAward?AWD_ID=1900087&HistoricalAwards=false),"><strong>Award Number: 1900087</strong>
    </a> $299,962, 2019-2022. </li>

      <li>NSF, “Targeted Infusion Project: “Integrating Data Science into the Urban Studies and Sustainability Program”, <a href="https://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/showAward?AWD_ID=1912214&HistoricalAwards=false"><strong>Award Number: 1912214</strong>
    </a> $249,825.00, 2019-2022. </li>


    </ul>
    <!--close button_small-->
  </div>
  <!--close content_container-->
</div>





<div id="content">
  <div class="content_item">
  
    <h1>Previous Fundings </h1>

    <ul>
      <li><b>UNC Research Cyberinfrastructure Colaboration Grant</b></li>
      Senior personnel: Dr. Debzani Deb, WSSU
      <li><b>WSSU RIP Award</b></li>
      “Utility-based Resource Provisioning of Big Data Applications on Cloud Environment”<br /> Amount: $9,690.00<br /> June, 2016 to November, 2017<br /> PI: Dr. Debzani Deb, WSSU

    </ul>

  </div>
  <!--close content_container-->
</div>
```

Comment: did you consider the margin of the h1?

Comment: On a side note, `id` should have an unique value